# Joomla Component Development: Searchable category form field

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, custom-component

I am creating a custom component which allows the backend user to associate a content category with an record in my database table. I would like to have the same form field that is displayed throughout the backend in Joomla where the user is able to filter/search the categories in the drop down by typing.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tne6l.png)

[The joomla website](https://docs.joomla.org/Category_form_field_type) provides this code example:

```
<field name="mycategory" type="category" extension="com_content" label="Select a category" description="" />
```

However this only creates a standard drop-down select box that is not searchable.

Looking in 'administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/artile.xml' the category field is listed as:

```
    <field name="catid"
           type="categoryedit"
        label="JCATEGORY"
           description="JFIELD_CATEGORY_DESC"
        required="true"
           default=""
    >
    </field>
```

However this gives me a simple text box to enter the category ID into.

How can I easily get the searchable dropdown without programming it from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

The category field type is a standard form field type so it is available to you anywhere you are creating a form in joomla. You can read more about standard form fields at https://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types. However the categoryedit field type is something unique/custom to the category manager component. You can read more about custom form fields at https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type.

In order for you to use custom fields in xml you must declare a path to the where the fields are stored by using addfieldpath attribute in the fieldset tag of your xml file.

Example

```
<fieldset addfieldpath="/administrator/components/<component name>/models/fields"></fieldset>
```

In the example up above the  would be com_categories so the full path to use categoryedit would be

```
<fieldset addfieldpath="administrator/components/com_categories/models/fields"></fieldset>
```

Comment: This didn't change anything. I still get the same category drop down without the autocomplete feature.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to the template enables the autocomplete feature.

```
JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select', null, array('disable_search_threshold' => 0 ));
```